# How to switch Tumblr account in my app

Tags: android, tumblr

I made an android app which user can share url to Tumblr.I use a webview to load the authorization page. Here is the problem:
 After user inputs his username and password and click the "allow" button, it doesn't let user to input  username and password again. That means I can't use another tumblr account to sign in again.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect your user to https://www.tumblr.com/logout to log them out of the current account. Redirect to https://www.tumblr.com/login afterwards to show the login screen again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already solved the problem by clear WebView's cookies. thanks again.